# MySql how to generate a complete calendar from an interval?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm new to mysql procedures. I ask your help for generate an calendar with some kind of procedure (generate a row for every day in an interval)... on stackoverflow i found this function:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
    BEGIN

          WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
            INSERT INTO mytable (mydate) VALUES (dateStart);
            SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
          END WHILE;
        END;


    CALL filldates('2014-01-01','2014-12-31');
```

But gives me an error near `INSERT INTO mytable (mydate) VALUES (dateStart);` I use **MySql 5.5.35-33** and i will run the query on PhpMyAdmin. I tried the query alone but it work as it should. 
An php solution it's ok too... also some kind of generator of .sql file to import etc thanks :D

The result must be something like that table:

```
  ID | Date       | Price | ..
______________________________
   0 | 2014-01-01 |   40  | ..
   1 | 2014-01-02 |   40  | ..
   2 | 2014-01-03 |   40  | ..
 ... |    ...     |  ...  |
 365 | 2014-12-31 |   40  | ..
```

If you know how to generate this kind of table i will be very **grateful**.

Others mysql infos

```
innodb_version : 5.5.35-rel33.0
protocol_version : 10
slave_type_conversions 
version : 5.5.35-33.0-log
version_comment: Percona Server (GPL), Release rel33.0, Revision 61...
version_compile_machine : x86_64
version_compile_os : Linux
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your table has got at least this `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE mytable(
  ID INT,
  date DATE,
  Price INT
);
```

Then you could insert rows for every day of the year with following statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, date, Price)
SELECT
    t.n, 
    DATE_ADD('2014-01-01', INTERVAL t.n DAY),
    40
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) c
    ORDER BY n
) t   
WHERE
    t.n <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2014-01-01', '2014-12-31');
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5fdc/1)

**Explanation**

The subselect creates a temporary table with a row for every day between start ('2014-01-01') and end ('2014-12-31'). So MySQL has only to do one single INSERT and this is much faster than a row by row insert.

If you only want the dates, omit the columns `ID` and `Price` that I took from your example:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (date)
SELECT
    DATE_ADD('2014-01-01', INTERVAL t.n DAY)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7) c
    ORDER BY n
) t   
WHERE
    t.n <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2014-01-01', '2014-12-31');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help...i pasted your code in SQL 'Tab' on PhpMyAdmin but as result i get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_ADD('2014-07-01', INTERVAL t.n DAY),

Comment: I missed a comma in the first line of the select, fixed now. Had another typo too, added fiddle.

Comment: Ok seems to work but i have an conflict with this #1136 - 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' , can you do somthing to generate only the date column values, please? In future i would like to take the same ids . Thanks in advice :D

Comment: Your column list in the `INSERT` statement must match the column count in the `SELECT` statement. Added date-only solution.

Comment: I tried to re-run the query but i have this error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
    FROM
        ' at line 4 " I never used temporary tables before so sorry for my "dumbness". Actually i dont have time to study it well so sorry for bothering. I promise that i will learn more as soon as possible :)

Comment: My bad, I've left a comma by removing the not needed columns, same mistake as first try. Corrected now. Time to go to bed!

Comment: THANKS YOU MEN :D Worked like a charm!

Comment: Before you go to sleep (in Italy it's almost midnight), one last thing: how do I create a table type for 2 years? When I do the query even on SQL-fiddle it stops to 499 records ...

Comment: You've got to expand the third row of the UNION. I ended it with 4, so the greatest number will 499. You need at least a 7. Same timezone here in Germany.

Comment: @VMai Demo link's dead/empty.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It seems sqlfiddle has got currently a problem. IE presents me an error message if I try to create a fiddle.

Comment: @VMai Ah, ok. I guess it stands at coming back when they've "shoo'd" the bugs out of the system lol - Thanks for the update, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- It shows us why answers that rely on external sources only are low quality answers. Added minimal `CREATE TABLE` statement for copy and paste if one's got his own MySQL server.

Comment: @VMai That was a good idea. I did +1 originally, great answer! Somebody posted a question a little while ago asking about calendar creation and thought of your answer. Whether they'll use it or not, is up to them. I did save that fiddle in a file though when the demo was up, but that's not really a requirement anyway. But you're right about not having to rely on external sources. *Cheers!*